# EnumDesktopWindows не видит окно поиск Windows10

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]В общем задача такая, что мне нужно проверить не перекрывает ли какое-нибудь окно моё приложение. Для этого я использую [EnumDesktopWindows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdesktopwindows), в коллбеке которой проверяю не перекрывает ли какое-нибудь окно моё приложение. Заметил, что если открыть окно поиска в Windows 10 (win + s), то коллбек не вызывается для окна поиска.
Вот пример тестового кода:

```
BOOL CALLBACK MyCallback(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    wchar_t strText[256];

    GetClassName(hwnd, strText, 256);

    wcout << strText << endl;

    if (wcscmp(strText, L"SearchPane") == 0)
    {
        wcout << L"***** DONE *****" << endl;
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    Sleep(6000);
    ::EnumDesktopWindows(nullptr, MyCallback, NULL);
}
```

Запускаю приложение, в течение 6 секунд жму Win + S и жду пока приложение отработает. В итоге "DONE" не печатается и в списке классов окон нет окна с классом SearchPane. Хотя утилита inspect.exe (из Windows kits) находит (ей я и узнал, что имя класса этого окна SearchPane).
Пробовал добавить в манифест приложения `<disableWindowFiltering>true</disableWindowFiltering>`
Но не помогло, хотя, не исключаю, что неправильно пробовал добавить.
Может знает кто, как заставить мой коллбек отрабатывать и для окна поиска?

Comment: Название класса этого окна `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow`

Comment: В поле ClassName утилиты inspect показано SearchPane, именно это значение, как мне кажется, должна вернуть функция GetClassName.

Comment: А какая у вас сборка системы? И прикрепите скриншот, как у вас иерархия окон выглядит. У меня 1803 и окон с классом `SearchPane` вообще нет.

Comment: @VVT, окно это появляется в списке после того как при запущеной утилитке inspect.exe нажать Win + S

Comment: Хмм. [на моей системе это выглядит по-другому](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iI8wo.png)

Comment: Действительно. А вы на вашей системе можете найти это окно с помощью кода, приведённого выше (если заменить название окна)?

Comment: Да. Еще посмотрел на англоязычной редакции - там заголовок у окона `Cortana`, а имя класса такое же. Может у вас Windows LTSB?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83701/discussion-between-rudolfninja-and-vtt).

Comment: EnSo [EnumWindows function in Win10 enumerates only desktop apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38205375/enumwindows-function-in-win10-enumerates-only-desktop-apps)

Comment: @VTT, спасибо. Будем считать, что впорос решён